# Logback error: no applicable action for [tag-name], current ElementPath is [tag-path]

Tags: java, logback

When deploying my war in JBoss, the error is coming in logback config XML and the deployment fails

I am using logback.xml in spring boot applications because i can't use separate logback-spring.xml as there are other application which can't use logback-spring.xml. when I include [maxHistor] or [totalSizeCap] tab i am getting error like

```
no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy][maxHistory]]
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <property name="NIF_LOG_HOME" value="/tpv/apps/jboss/jboss-eap-7.1/app_logs/NIF"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d ${APP_NAME} %-5level [%thread] %logger: %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="NIF-AUDIT"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${NIF_LOG_HOME}/nif.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${NIF_LOG_HOME}/archived/nif.archived.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
                <maxHistory>20</maxHistory>
                <totalSizeCap>2GB</totalSizeCap>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="com.tmna.toms.nif" additivity="false" level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="NIF-AUDIT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

I expect the war to be deployed but it is not because of the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
00:53:23,304 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 170) ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@24:29 - no applicable action for [maxHistory], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][rollingPolicy][timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy][maxHistory]]
00:53:23,304 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 170)  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:161)
```

Comment: But when i remove those tags, it is getting deployed

Comment: What version of Logback are you using? I've found [this](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-747) - a but that seems to be very similar to yours problem. From my understanding it should be fixed in version 1.1.7